# How to add job dependency to gerrit trigger in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

We do have this configuration in our GUI based Jenkins project, trying to convert it to Jenkins pipeline, couldn't find how to add `precurse-build` as dependent build as shown in red below.

[image: Gerrit Trigger Plugin options]

I added below below pipeline code to trigger the build when`run_job` is added as gerrit comment, and it works good, would anyone please show me how to add `Other jobs on which this job depends` to this?

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
         gerrit dynamicTriggerConfiguration: 'true',
                triggerConfigURL: 'https://some/url/path/trigger.txt',
                serverName: 'gerrit-server',
                triggerOnEvents: [
                    commentAddedContains('^run_job$')
                ]
    }

    stages {
       ...
       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to determine the names for Pipeline step parameters is to use the Pipeline Snippet generator in the web UI:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator

However, based on browsing the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/b614e75a03b3d75afa63197b035031d905c36a4d/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger/GerritTrigger.java), I am guessing the name of the parameter you are looking for is `dependencyJobsNames`.